# Why do I get low frequency audio buzz during recording?

Tags: microphone, interference

So I have a semi-ghetto system set up for recording on my PC using a shure sm58 microphone, it is on a modified lamp stand to suspend it in mid air, so it has no chance of vibration interference, and I have tried using both audacity and OBS to record, and it is crystal clear, but as soon as I boot up a game, in this case firewatch, it has a horrible constant buzz in the background. Here is a link to a sound clip of it:

http://www.mediafire.com/listen/adb4sv35gz9gika

That goes on constantly whenever a game is running. It seems to possibly be linked to how graphically intensive the game is, firewatch being quite intense, leading me to think interference from the gpu, but I am using internal sound of my motherboard, which claims to be isolated. Should I get an dedicated sound card?

I have already ruled out the mic and the mixer board I'm using as it works perfectly anytime I am not recording, or using my mic. Is it a fault with my mobo? Should there be shielding in front of the audio segment of my mobo? Please help, thanks.

Comment: Before you get a dedicated audio interface (which is always a good idea for recording) maybe you might get a mic stand?